# How do I keep score in a rock paper scissors game?

Tags: python

I'm just starting Python and writing a simple rock paper scissors game. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/WRjm1txL) what I have so far. I can play a game with another player perfectly. What I want to know is how to keep score of the wins, so if Player 1 wins the first game it would say:

Player 1 = 1
Player 2 = 0

And so on. Also if there's any tips to make my code more efficient (with a nice explanation), that would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: "More objects". :) Consider that each Player is an object, with a Name and a Score. "More functions". Consider there is a function that, when given the input, will display who wins and updates the appropriate Player score.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this pseudo-code for suggestions (some parts need to be implemented):

```
# a Player class. it should have a Name and a Score
class Player():
   def __init__(name):
      self.name = name
      self.score = 0

# displays a prompt and reads in the players name returning a string
def getPlayerName():
   # needs code here, see next function for idea of what
   pass

# ask the player to make a choice, takes a Player object
# and returns a string
def getPlayerAttack(player):
    print "%s, what do you choose?" % player.name
    return raw_input("> ")

# determines who wins and updates score accordingly
# takes in the player objects and their attack choices
def attack(player1, choice1, player2, choice2): 
    if choice1 == choice2:
       print "Its's a tie."
    elif choice1 == "1" and choice2 == "2":
       print "%s wins." % player2
       player2.score = player2.score + 1
    elif ... # other attacks

# display the scores of the two players
def displayScores(player1, player2):
    print "%s vs %s" % (player1.score, player2.score)

player1 = Player(getPlayerName())
player2 = Player(getPlayerName())
while true:
    choice1 = getPlayerAttack(player1)
    choice2 = getPlayerAttack(player2)
    attack(player1, choice1, player2, choice2)
    displayScores(player1, player2)
```

This will need some work, and it's *not* super-optimal, but it should be a start and should show some more concepts. Use Ctrl-C to stop or add a stop condition (e.g. either player enters "0") -- bugs included for free. :)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several ways to make it more efficient, but I have to ask how you are going to play Rock Paper Scissors if you have to type them in one at a time :-P

The scoring could be boiled down to this:

```
if choice1 == choice2 :
    print "Its's a tie."
elif choice1 - choice2 == 1 or choice2 - choice1 == 2 :
    print "%s wins." % player1
else:
    print "%s wins." % player2
```

If you want to do multiple games, just put the whole thing inside a `while(1):` loop, and add a variable for each score. Then it would become:

```
score1 = 0
score2 = 0
while(1):
    <lines 6-18>

    if choice1 == choice2 :
        print "Its's a tie."
    elif choice1 - choice2 == 1 or choice2 - choice1 == 2 :
        print "%s wins." % player1
        score1 = score1 + 1
    else:
        print "%s wins." % player2
        score2 = score2 + 1

    print "%s: %d points. %s: %d points." % (player1, score1, player2, score2)
```

Comment: I forgot about the typing them one at a time thing (I guess Player 2 has an unfair advantage!), but I just wanted some practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
player1 = raw_input("Player 1 name: ")
player2 = raw_input("Player 2 name: ")
while(1)
    player1score = 0
    player2score = 0

    print "%s, what do you choose?" % player1
    print "1. Rock"
    print "2. Paper"
    print "3. Scissors"

    choice1 = raw_input("> ")

    print "%s, what do you choose?" % player2
    print "1. Rock"
    print "2. Paper"
    print "3. Scissors"

    choice2 = raw_input("> ")

    if choice1 == "1" and choice2 == "1":
        print "Its's a tie."

    if choice1 == "1" and choice2 == "2":
        print "%s wins." % player2
        player2score=player2score+1

    if choice1 == "2" and choice2 == "1":
        print "Player 1 wins." % player1
        player1score=player1score+1

    if choice1 == "1" and choice2 == "3":
        print "Player 1 wins." % player1
        player1score=player1score+1

    if choice1 == "3" and choice2 == "1":
        print "%s2 wins." % player2
        player2score=player2score+1

    if choice1 == "2" and choice2 == "3":
        print "%s wins." % player2
        player2score=player2score+1

    if choice1 == "3" and choice2 == "2":
        print "Player 1 wins." % player1
        player1score=player1score+1

    print "Player1: %s" % player1score 
    print "Player2: %s" % player2score
```